# No module - importing pyotp

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, nomodule

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyotp'
While doing

I am getting the above error.

Please note I already installed pyotp  2.9.0

I can see that in the pip list

Even I can import pandas without error.

Is there any way to find the physical path of the installed package's path?

Comment: Please check that the python binary you're using is in the same python environment that you installed those packages.